# JavaFX Display Applications on two monitors full screen

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I have applications with two stages . I want to display one stage on one monitor on full screen. I don't know how I can do it. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote someone eleses answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936617/choose-which-monitor-does-a-javafx-window-open-in)

> You can iterate Screen.getScreens() and move your stage to required one. See example below.

Specifically the screen class as mentioned:

```
  for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreens()) {
            Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

            Button btn = new Button("Move me to Screen " + index++);
            btn.setOnAction((e) -> {
                stage.setX(bounds.getMinX() + 100);
                stage.setY(bounds.getMinY() + 100);
            });
            root.getChildren().add(btn);
        }
```

This will essentially use the bounds of each screen allocated to each screen and you can then set the X and Y value of each stage you wish to move to whichever screen.

Hope this helps, if you have any issues let me know and good luck with your project!