# How to identify opened window is on which monitor while using primary and secondary monitors: JavaFx

Tags: javafx, stage

I am using multiple monitors, before I open popup from main window I need to check the main window is currently active(opened) on which monitor.
How can check in JavaFx.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936617/choose-which-monitor-does-a-javafx-window-open-in) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Screens.getScreensForRectangle`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getScreensForRectangle(double,double,double,double)). Using the bounds of your window you should be able to get a list of the screens used to display it's area:

```
List<Screen> windowScreens = Screens.getScreensForRectangle(window.getX(), window.getY(),
                                                            window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
```